# Вставить значение в определенную ячейку определенной строки

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, как вставить значение в определенную ячейку в нужной строке через js
есть таблица вида

```
<table>
 <tr id="1">
  <td id="1"></td>
  <td id="2"></td>
  <td id="3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="2">
  <td id="1"></td>
  <td id="2"></td>
  <td id="3"></td>
 </tr>
```

Так вот, надо вставить значение в ячейку через id строки и ячейки в которую вставлять надо.

Пытался разными способоами, но ничего не выходит

Comment: `id` должны быть уникальными на всей странице. Введите свой пользовательский атрибут вроде `data-id` или обращайтесь к ячейке по порядковому номеру строки и порядковому номеру ячейки в дереве DOM.

Comment: что то подобное реализовал)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем HTML ошибка. `id` не могут быть одинаковые [по определению](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). «The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.» Исправьте это, и после этого сможете искать элементы по `id`.

Чтобы найти элемент по его `id`, используйте `document.getElementById()`.

А чтобы поменять значение внутри элемента, можете использовать property `innerHTML`.

И так получаем:

```
document.getElementById('2_1').innerHTML = 'artes';
```

Comment: исправил. id у столбца одинаковые в каждой строке. именно поэтому мне и надо занести значение в столбец 2 строки 2, но как именно это сделать не пойму.

Comment: @artes: id не могут быть одинаковые [по определению](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). «The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) **which must be unique in the whole document**.»

Comment: ну во первых там написано, что не должны, а не не могут по определению. Во вторых никто и нигде не запрещает задавать элементам одинаковые id( используется везде и всюду для удобного добавления всем нужным стилям сразу, а не каждому элементу по отдельности)

Comment: @artes: Один господин очень любил на красный свет улицу переходить. Однажды, его покалечила машина, и когда ему сказали, что зря он игнорирует светофор, он начал припираться: «никто и нигде не запрещает переходить на красный», «везде и всюду переходят», и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали в комментариях id html элементов должны быть уникальными. Поэтому я предлагаю вот такое решение без использования дублированных id

```js
replaceCellContent(1, 1, 'content 1 1')
replaceCellContent(1, 2, 'content 1 2')
replaceCellContent(1, 3, 'content 1 3')

replaceCellContent(2, 1, 'content 2 1')
replaceCellContent(2, 2, 'content 2 2')
replaceCellContent(2, 3, 'content 2 3')

function replaceCellContent(rowNumber, cellNumber, content) {
  const selector = `#app-table tr:nth-of-type(${rowNumber}) > td:nth-of-type(${cellNumber})`
  const cellElement = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (cellElement) {
    cellElement.textContent = content;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="app-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var td_date = document.getElementById(date_event_from).children;
    for(var j=0, child; child=td_date[j]; j++) {
        if(child.dataset.id == event_id){
            child.innerHTML = text_event;
        }
                                        
    }
```

event_id - переменная которая равна td id и data-id.
date_event_from - переменная которая равна  tr id.
получили всех потомков в строке. дальше перебираем их через цикл. Делаем проверку, что если data id равен переменной, то заносим значение в этого потомка в нужной строке